# Obtaining the value column key inside a cell renderer?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin, nebular

Is it possible to obtain the column key inside a cell renderer?

For example in the [`CustomRenderComponent Demo](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/custom-edit-view/custom-render.component.ts) the value of the cell and the row data is injected like this:

```
@Input() value: string | number;
@Input() rowData: any;
```

is there a way to get the current column key?  Something like:

```
@input column: string;
```

or get a [Cell](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/ng2-smart-table/lib/data-set/cell.ts) instance?

The `Cell` class has method like this:

```
getColumn(): Column {
  return this.column;
}
```

## Smart Table Issue

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/518

Comment: Basically what you want ? Do you want to access row or column data ?

Comment: Yes - In the repository example the renderer only receives the cell `value` and `rowData`.  I'm also wondering what column the cell is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [custom-view.component.ts](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/ng2-smart-table/components/cell/cell-view-mode/custom-view.component.ts).  It has a method `getPatch()` that returns a `ViewCell`.  Change this method to return a `Cell`.

Now the custom renderer implementation will be patched with the entire `Cell` instance, rather than a few of the components belonging to it.

Create a new interface that this type of renderer should implement, rather than just having it implement the `ViewCell` interface.

Comment: IIUC the `row.data` is the same thing as the `rowData` that the custom render component inherits from the `ViewCell` interface?

Comment: @Ole that you have to check in your case. When I console.log(row). I got the data in `row.data`.

Comment: Yes that's what I get too.  Looks like the custom cell renderer has to be redesigned in order to pass the column value to the component.  I'm working on it now.  I'll post an update as soon as the prototype is ready.

Comment: @Ole ok anything else for me ?

Comment: I changed your answer with the implementation approach I'm going to use.

Comment: NP - Also added a link I found to my question for an issue that's been open for a while that asks for this to be implemented.